# gitolite on ubuntu 12 always asking for password when trying to clone gitolite-admin

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitolite

after several hours of googling and trying (and reading several posts on this page) I still do not know what I am doing wrong. So I would be very happy, if somebody could help me here...

I updated Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.4 LTS and thus had to switch vom gitosis to gitolite (the update removed the deprecated gitosis package; gitosis worked nicely before).
I disabled the old gitosis installation (user gitosis) by removing the authorized_keys and the post update hook and then follwed this tutorial to install gitolite:
http://cisight.com/how-to-setup-git-server-using-gitolite-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

Everything up to (including) the following line worked fine:

```
gl-setup /temp/gitadmin.pub
```

However, when I try to clone (on the same computer with my personal user which has the private key to gitadmin.pub), I am asked to enter the password of "git". However, git has no password (I created a new git user as follows:

```
sudo adduser --system --shell /bin/sh --gecos 'git version control' --group --disabled-password --home /home/git git
```

)

Can anybody help me and tell me what I am missing here!?
Thanks!

PS: Git clone from a public github repo works (git was setup up with gitosis some time ago)

Comment: Are you using a config file to reference the private key? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461

Comment: As far as I understand this post, the config file is a client thing? I also tried from a windows client (the same way it worked with the gitosis installation) - but this did not work either. I think it is something with the server setup???

Comment: `config` is a ssh file, put in the `~/.ssh` directory in order to specify where the private ssh key is. It also works on Windows, provided you defined first the `%HOME%` environment variable. To further debug your issue, you should edit your question with the result of `ssh -vvv user@server`. This is first and foremost an ssh issue, but check if your `gitoliteadmin.pub` is registered on the server side in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to change your sshd_config file:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

or add

```
Match User yourUser

     PasswordAuthentication no
```